# Data Replacement based on conditions in R

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

I am trying to find an equivalent to if, then, else in R for data replacement.

Example using iris R data set.

I want to be able to calculate and replace data with the following type of condition:

```
IF Sepal.Width >= 2.8 and <= 3.1 AND petal.length < 1.4 THEN petal.length = 1.
```

Haven't figured out how to do this in R.  I know you can set conditions to specific columns, but I need it to evaluate the values of a column to determine which columns need the adjustment.  I have seen several examples but none evaluate 2 columns before determining the replace.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: `df[ df$Sepal.Width >= 2.8 & df$Sepal.Width <= 3.1 &df$petal.length < 1.4,"petal.length"] = 1`

Comment: @Codoremifa: Why not upgrading your comment to a real answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can do something like this - very similar to what Codoremifa suggested above.

```
    df$Petal.Length[df$Sepal.Width >= 2.8 & df$Sepal.Width <= 3.1 & df$Petal.Length < 1.4 ] = 1
```